# r documentation on methods used by a test?

Tags: r

R provides a number of `.test`s for various applications.  It is often the case that there are many methods in the literature for a test.  For example, a test of a population proportion probably has at least a half dozen possible tests.  Each of these has various properties, and they may make different assumptions.

The base R documentation seems to not always give much information on precisely which method is used for a test.  For example `?prop.test` does not mention whether the Wald method or Wilson method (or some other method) is used.

Is this information documented somewhere?  How can I find out more about which methods are being used by a particular test in R?

Comment: They refer to Wilson though in the References.

Comment: @jay.sf I noticed this.  However, they also cite a paper titled "Two-Sided Confidence Intervals for the Single Proportion: Comparison of Seven Methods."

Answer (score 3):

One option is to view and dissect the source code: `getAnywhere(prop.test)`

While possibly tedious, it gives an unambiguous explanation for what is actually happening when you run a function.